# Presenting and dismissing a view Causes exception

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two `UIViewControllers` “viewcontroller1” and “viewcontroller2”

In **viewcontroller1**

```
-(IBAction)AddClicked:(id)sender
{
   viewcontroller2 *view=[[viewcontroller2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller2” bundle:nil];
  view.str=@"Main";
[self presentViewController: view animated:NO completion:nil];
 [view release];
  }
```

In **viewcontroller2**

```
 -(IBAction)BackClicked:(id)sender
 { 
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

after Add clicked view2 is loaded sucessfully.after clicking back view2 is dismissedsucessfully.
But if i try to click on add again getting an exception that

**viewcontroller2** was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  **(
 Context: 0xf7dea8, Property: 0x17f292d0>
 Context: 0xf7dea8, Property: 0x19070e90>
)'**

*** First throw call stack:

**(0x2b6b4f87 0x39051c77 0x2b6b4ecd 0x2c35c18b 0x70c517 0x2c3b85e9 0x2b67b737 0x2b67b2b9 0x2b679523 0x2b5c6db1 0x2b5c6bc3 0x328fb051 0x2eb92a31 0xc1a1d 0xb3698)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

if i remove the  `[view release];` getting memory leakage.

How can I achieve neither exception nor leak ?

Comment: And have you tried googling the error message? I'm sure it's been covered a zillion times.

Comment: sry what is MRC, i know about ARC which we r not using

Comment: The error says there's a problem with "key value observers" but your question shows nothing related to KVO.  What is `Context` and how is it related to the view controllers?

Comment: while presenting the 2nd viewcontroller why r u not animating? change animation to `animated:YES`

Comment: this code looks fine the problem is somewhere else add the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you registering to notifications or adding observers to viewcontroller2?

You have to remove them before deallocating the view controller.

Comment: i have property string in view2, which i was sent frm view1

Comment: Thanks, it was due to some public classes which i added for some purpose,in that classes some observers are added to that viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks Rami, you made my day !!

Answer (score 2):

Try autorelease

```
viewcontroller2 *view = [[[viewcontroller2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller2” bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: autorelease still getting exception

Comment: then try to release it in completion block

Comment: That is all not a good solution. When the viewController is presented, the system helds a retain on it and you can release it like the TO did.Take a look at the answer from Rami. Perhaps that might help.